# How to check the driver is on the route or not in android (Re_route Process )

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-android-api-2, reroute

I am working in an android application and I have two apps one is rider app and another is driver app. In Driver, I get the driver current location and send it to the server and In rider side, one API for rider end that gets the driver location and set to the rider side map to move the driver marker. In the rider side, how I know the driver is on the route line or not.

I have done some R&D but not get a proper conclusion.

My Question is In rider side how to check the driver is on the route line or not?

Thanks In Advance